# How to use smarty in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

I have some prior experience in PHP programming but I had used Smarty as my template engine, and found it easy to use. I read that Drupal is making use of PHPTemplate as template engine. So, I just wanted to know how to implement Smarty template engine in Drupal?

Comment: Drupal 8 will include [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), together PHPTemplate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While there is a [Smarty](http://drupal.org/project/smarty) module, it has no release for Drupal 7 and I doubt there will be one.

For Drupal 4 and 5, there were various efforts made to use different template engines.  However, nearly all contributed themes for Drupal 6 and 7 are done in PHPTemplate and almost all documentation and available support are for PHPTemplate.

Even if you're already familiar with Smarty, if you're going to use Drupal seriously for more than one project I would highly recommend learning PHPTemplate.  At this point, you would have to do work to integrate Smarty into Drupal 7 on your own, which would almost certainly be harder than just learning PHPTemplate.  Going with Smarty will also limit your support options.

Comment: thank you! I will look into PHPTemplate, as I want to go with latest version of Drupal. I think this is going to be exciting!!

Comment: Still no release for 7.x and 8.x :( ??